# Live USB for Ubuntu 13.10 does't recognize Windows 8 OS

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, live-usb, uefi

I have created a Live USB for Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.4.4

I have restarted and booted from the USB; tried Ubuntu without installing. Everything works fine there including web browsing, videos, installing new software etc. So I decide to install Ubuntu as dual boot option to Windows 8.

When I tried installing, the options do not show the existing Windows 8 OS. It shows only the option to install Ubuntu as standalone OS. The step by step installation instructions available online mention that it should show option like "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8"

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 with Windows 8; UEFI boot. I have 3 options for the boot menu: "UEFI Security boot On", "UEFI Security boot Off" and "Legacy boot".

Please advise how I can get to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I know that USB setup is good as I am able to boot and try from it without installing. May be boot settings?

Thanks in Advance!
~KK

Comment: is there any `something else` option present.

Comment: Yes I see a something else option - it shows me sda1,2,3 for the windows partition,recovery and some other partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Choose `something else` option,select the partition you want to install ubuntu.Please dont select any windows partition.Then format the selected partition to `ext4 filesystem`,and choose the install option.It will take you to the installation progress 
  window.

Comment: It did cross my mind but I don't want to lose my Windows 8. If I do so and Install Ubuntu, will I see both Windows and Ubuntu in boot menu?

Comment: you see both windows and ubuntu on boot menu.But make sure that the partition where you are going to install ubuntu is not a windows `c` drive partition.

Comment: Thanks for your help!Hopefully I will post my next comment from Ubuntu installation :)