# Ubuntu 13.10 installer not Detecting Windows 8 Partitions

Tags: dual-boot, disk, partitioning

I have a 1Tb hardisk with windows 8 installed on a 70 Gb partition 
the ubuntu installer wont detect my windows 8 and other partitions.
inside ubuntu i can see my other disks , but the installer only sees my hard ask 1 tb
Please Suggest a Solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Live USB for Ubuntu 13.10 does't recognize Windows 8 OS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/376710/live-usb-for-ubuntu-13-10-doest-recognize-windows-8-os); however, if you mean that partitioning tools show the disk as completely empty, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/343768/why-is-it-not-showing-any-partitions

Comment: I have the same problem. the answer is not clear at all.
I don't see any partition separately but only the entire drive as one partition. I cannot take risk by selecting whole partition and install ubuntu by ruining my installed OS. need help about this.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I've had the same experience with ubuntu 13.10. But, after installing the grub menu was populated with a Windows 8 entry too, and I could dual boot without any problem.